# How to set width of html.textboxfor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have a `<%= Html.TextBoxFor(user => user.Name) %>` and it has standart width.

What should I do to make textbox wider?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this to add a CSS class called `singleTextBox`, and then you can assign a  width in your style sheet:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { @class = "singleTextBox" }) %>
```

In your style sheet:

```
.singleTextBox {
    width: 12em;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

you can also do using css style, its that simple and worked great for me

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { style = "width: 250px;" })
```

got this idea from Darin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7615377/2218697) for DropdownList width.

hope helps someone.