# Width of my input fields in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I just started using MVC3. I am using fields like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Status.RowKey, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
                </div>
```

Which creates this HTML

```
<div class="editor-field">
                    <input disabled="disabled" id="Status_RowKey" name="Status.RowKey" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="0001" />
            </div>
```

But I notice all the input fields have the same width which is about 160px. Is there a way I can make them wider and why do they default to this. In my editor-field class I

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to set width of html.textboxfor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575067/how-to-set-width-of-html-textboxfor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the size property:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Status.RowKey, new { size = 200, disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Probably more appropriate would be set the input width in css and give the textbox a class, like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Status.RowKey, new { @class = "myClass", disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })

<style>
  input.myClass { width = 200px; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way I can directly set the width in the first line without using a class?

Comment: Thanks. I just saw u also told me how to do that. Works great

Answer (score 2):

If your fields do not have any styling your browser will apply it's own default width to them.  You need to add a style to them

By adding an external CSS file containing

```
div.editor-field input { width: 300px; }
```

Or by inline (not recomended)

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Status.RowKey, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly", style="width:300px" })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS for that.

For example:

```
input#StatusRowKey /* matches only the textfield with id StatusRowKey */
{
   width: 250px;
}
input              /* matches all input types */
{
   width: 200px;
}
input.Normal /* matches all input fields with class="Normal" */
{
   width: 100px;
}
```