# @Html.DropDownList width

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Q: How to set width for @Html.DropDownList (and not in css)?

```
@Html.DropDownList("ListId", String.Empty, new {style="width: 250px;"})  @* no go!*@
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The second argument of the [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470380.aspx) helper must be an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. You are passing a string (an empty one to be more precise). So in order to use this helper you will have to respect its signature:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "ListId", 
    Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), 
    new { style = "width: 250px;" }
)
```

Obviously generating an empty dropdown list is of little use. You probably have a view model (you should by the way) that you want to use to bind to:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "ListId", 
    Model.MyList, 
    new { style = "width: 250px;" }
)
```

and of course because you have a view model you should prefer to use the `DropDownListFor` helper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ListId, 
    Model.MyList, 
    new { style = "width: 250px;" }
)
```

and finally to avoid cluttering your HTML with styles you should use an external CSS:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.ListId, 
    Model.MyList, 
    new { @class = "mycombo" }
)
```

where in your external CSS you would define the `.mycombo` rule:

```
.mycombo {
    width: 250px;
}
```

Now you have what I consider a proper code.

Comment: Is it possible to replace  Model.MyList with ViewBag somehow ?

Comment: @Peretz, yes, it's possible, but not something I would recommend. Using a view model is a much better approach.

Comment: If that is enclosed within, let's say a bootstrap control, you must set the width as "width: 250px !important;" to be applied.

Answer (score 6):

You should use the View Model approach. However the lazy way out is just to give the 2nd parameter a null.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ListId", null, new {style="width: 250px;"})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Test,
 new SelectList(new List<YourNamespace.Modelname>(), "Id", "Name"), 
 null, new { @id = "ddlTest", @style="width: 250px;" })
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a jquery technique that allows you to set the width without having to deal with the @Html.DropDownList constructor.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ListId").width(300);
    });
</script>
```